# Why, when attempting to unsubscribe from an event, is the event handler object not recognised?

Tags: c#, events, .net-4.0, observer-pattern, unsubscribe

This has turned out to be quite a lengthy question, so thank you in advance to all those who give up their time to read it and comment/answer :)

### Edits

- This Question has been majorly simplified.
- Example code is now a complete, simple program

I am **using an observer pattern** implemented through interfaces:

```
public interface IObserver<in T>where T:EventArgs
{
    void Update(object sender, T e);
}

public interface ISubject<in T, TU>where TU:EventArgs
{
    event EventHandler<TU> Notify;

    T State { set; }

    void Attach(Action<object,TU> callback);
    void Detach(Action<object, TU> callback);
}
```

I have created two simple classes which implement these interfaces
The `MyObserver` object will simply output a string to the console window when a `Notify` event is raised in the `MySubject` object.

```
    public class MyObserver:IObserver<TestEventArgs>
    {
        private ISubject<bool, TestEventArgs> _subject;

        public MyObserver(ISubject<bool, TestEventArgs> subject)
        {
            _subject = subject;
        }

        public void Subscribe()
        {
            _subject.Attach(Update);
        }

        public void Unsubscribe()
        {
            _subject.Detach(Update);
        }

        public void Update(object sender, TestEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.TestMessage);
        }
    }

    public class MySubject:ISubject<bool, TestEventArgs>
    {
        public void ObservableEvent(string message)
        {
            InvokeNotify(message);
        }

        private void InvokeNotify(string message)
        {
            EventHandler<TestEventArgs> handler = Notify;

            if(handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new TestEventArgs(message));
            }
        }

        public event EventHandler<TestEventArgs> Notify;

        public bool State
        {
            set { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public void Attach(Action<object, TestEventArgs> callback)
        {
            Notify += new EventHandler<TestEventArgs>(callback);
        }

        public void Detach(Action<object, TestEventArgs> callback)
        {
            Notify -= new EventHandler<TestEventArgs>(callback);
        }
    }

    public class TestEventArgs:EventArgs
    {
        public TestEventArgs(string message)
        {
            TestMessage = message;
        }

        public string TestMessage { get; private set; }
    }
```

This test program shows that:

- before `myObserver` has subscribed to the event no message is output to the Console window.
- after `myObserver` has subscribed to the `Notify` event the message is output to the Console window.
- after `myObserver` has UNsubscribed from the `Notify` event the message **is still output to the Console window**

  ```
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
      MySubject mySubject = new MySubject();
      MyObserver myObserver = new MyObserver(mySubject);

      //we have not subscribed to the event so this should not be output to the console
      mySubject.ObservableEvent("First Test");

      myObserver.Subscribe();

      //we are now subscribing to the event. This should be displayed on the console window
      mySubject.ObservableEvent("Second Test");

      myObserver.Unsubscribe();

      //We have unsubscribed from the event. I would not expect this to be displayed
      //...but it is!
      mySubject.ObservableEvent("Third Test");

      Console.ReadLine();
  }
  ```

The **issue** I'm having is that the **unsubscribe process is not working**.

I really don't understand why.

### Questions

- Why is the unsubscribe process not working?
- What happens when comparing 2 event handlers? How are they defined as equal or not? This may lead to an answer to why the invocation list `Contains` method always returns `false`.

Comment: um... the .NET framework already implements the observer pattern. Why are you making a new wheel here? Homework?

Comment: There's a *lot* of code here. Please try to produce a short but *complete* program which demonstrates the problem, without all the surrounding baggage.

Comment: @Brian: I wondered about the same thing and didn't ask it, because I didn't read the whole question and might have missed something. Anyway, the events in .NET are the implementation of the observer pattern, so basically, you, Lewray, use one implementation of the observer pattern to implement another?

Comment: @Brian - Fair Point, I guess after having the idea I got a bit carried away with implementing it myself and didn't think to check if there was an existing implementation. I'm not totally new to C# and .Net, but still have plenty to learn! - but on looking at the .NET IObservable<T>... why is there a Subscribe method, but no Unsubscribe?

Comment: @Jon - I know, there is a lot of baggage. I will see if I can replicate in a simpler environment and post the result as an edit or something.

Comment: @Daniel - Basically, I was repeating the same code to implement subscribing and unsubscribing. To me, it seemed this repitition could be better controlled and maintained if it were implemented as interfaces. I would welcome a correction or explanation of how I could simplify the scenario though. Am I wrong to create an Interface to encapsualte code which will be required in multiple classes but implemented slightly differently in each?

Comment: @Lewray: I didn't read your complete question, let alone the code, but a short answer to your comment: (1) It is correct to use an interface (2) You can control the addition and deletion of handlers even with the built in events, namely with the "property syntax" you are already using for your `Notify` event.

Comment: @Jon I have done my best to simplify things. I'd really appreciate any input you might have. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Lewray: Can you really not show it in fewer than 6 types? I'll take a look when I can, but the smaller the code I need to look at, the shorter the amount of time I need to find :)

Comment: @Lewray: `IObservable<T>.Subscribe` returns an IDisposable which will unsubscribe when you dispose it, IIRC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your problem is that this code:

```
public void Attach(Action<object, TestEventArgs> callback)
{
    Notify += new EventHandler<TestEventArgs>(callback);
}
```

Actually allocates a new object, as does the corresponding `Detach` code. So what's being detached isn't the same thing as what's being attached.

I'm not sure, but you might be able to fix it by changing your `Attach` and `Detach` so that they're:

```
void Attach(EventHandler<TU> callback);
void Detach(EventHandler<TU> callback);
```

And in the client code:

```
public void Attach(EventHandler<TestEventArgs> callback)
{
    Notify += callback;
}

public void Detach(EventHandler<TestEventArgs> callback)
{
    Notify -= callback;
}
```

I haven't actually tried to compile this, but it looks like it should work.

<strike>Or, if the compiler can do the type conversion:</strike>

```
public void Attach(Action<object, TestEventArgs> callback)
{
    Notify += callback;
}
```

Might be worth a shot.

Comment: I've run through this and it certainly solves the problem!  I think I was confused by this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/abhinaba/archive/2005/08/26/456437.aspx) stating that you can use either:  `+= new EventHandler(callback);`  or  `+= callback;`  But I suppose the key difference is that in their example they are using an `EventHAndler` object as their callback instead of an `Action`.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just for completeness... The last suggestion does not build, the `Action<object, TestEventArgs>` cannot be implicitly cast to an `EventHandler<TestEventArgs>`. Thanks again.

Comment: @Lewray: Glad you got it working. And thanks for the note about the last suggestion. I've edited my response.